# renderChatFeed property in react chat engine is rendering infinite loop of custom chat feed component

Tags: reactjs

```
//App.js file    
    import {ChatEngine} from "react-chat-engine";
    import './App.css';
    import ChatFeed from "./components/ChatFeed";
    
    const App =()=> {
  
  return (
    
     <ChatEngine
       height="100vh"
       projectID="0e3104a3-d472-4764-9990-2845352801b9"
       userName="Admin"
       userSecret="123123"
       renderChatFeed={(chatAppState) => <ChatFeed {...chatAppState}/>}
       //renderChatFeed={(chatAppProps)=>{ return <ChatFeed {...chatAppProps}/>}}
     />
   
  );
}


//ChatFeed component file
const ChatFeed = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
    return (
    <div>
      ChatFeed
    </div>);
}
 
export default ChatFeed;
```

i am using a custom chatFeed component using renderChatFeed function but the chat feed component does not stop rendering i dont understand whats the issue

Comment: I don't understand why you're doing this: `(chatAppState) => <ChatFeed {...chatAppState}/>`. Can you explain?

Comment: Sending all the props of chatEngine component to the custom chatFeed component by copying them using the "..." spread operator

Comment: can you post `ChatEngine` code?

Comment: I have posted it already

Comment: did you find any solution